# Is it harder today to earn reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Lately, browsing tons of questions on Stack Overflow, I have noticed that as the quality of (most of) the major tags (e.g PHP, Javascript, c#) seems to get worse and worse, answers to questions seem to be much less rated, and receive less attention.

I haven't been to this website 3-4 years ago, but I can definitely see that a lot of questions that were asked years ago received a lot of notice from other users, and almost every chosen answer I saw had at least 5-10 upvotes (today, most of them have 0-1).

So, clearly, it becomes harder to earn reputation on the website.

I can't be the only one who noticed that... Am I wrong here? And what are the reasons for that question&answer quality deterioration?

Comment: It's almost as if these older answers have had more time to gather votes!

Comment: @Patrice Not only votes, I mean that the discussion around earlier questions seems to be much richer and intense that discussions on currently asked questions. Meaning, more answers, explanations, etc.

Comment: @Stijn Interesting one.. Thanks for pointing there.

Comment: @YotamSalmon well they have been visible on the Internet for longer, which very well may explain all of this. My point was that it's hard to look at something from 5 years ago and compare it to something posted yesterday... the site evolves and changes.

Comment: @YotamSalmon _"Meaning, more answers, explanations, etc."_ Well, things become more FAQ like, and either questions are answered already, or policies were revised to narrow what can/should be asked.

Comment: Tag badges awarded per year might make a better metric for that than upvotes.

Comment: The bad questions from 3-4 years ago have had time to get deleted.   The 5 minute old questions haven't yet had time to get deleted.

Comment: "Is it harder today to earn reputation...?" Compared to what time period? I joined SO something like 2 years ago or less, and I can say that if you know some topic well enough, and this topic is popular enough, one can earn reputation relatively easily. For me, such kind of topic is Python, so I can earn some rep quickly by answering two or three simple Python questions.

Comment: @Louis Look at Stijn's answer... With that delay, if it were about baking a cake, your house would have been on fire ;-)

Comment: I'm feeling like this is a dupe because, well, most of the talking points have been hashed over in the other question.  If you're seeing a different discussion about this topic that isn't germane to what's already been provided, let me know and I'll see to reopen it.

Comment: Have you noticed most of the questions here will be marked as duplicated ?